# How to display image file after a change in the file system?

Tags: flutter

In the `build` method, I display an image from the file system, like so:

```
final String imagePath = ...;
final File file = File(imagePath);

return file.existsSync() ? Image.file(file) : SizedBox();
```

Sometimes the file doesn't exist, so later a script will download the image and save it to the same path.

After the file has been downloaded, I want the screen to refresh and display the image instead of the `SizedBox`.

I tried to `setState`, and even after the `build` method is being called again, I still see the `SizedBox`.

How can I do that? It's important that I don't change the file path.

Comment: Can you post code in `build` method?

Comment: @fartem This is the code in the build method. I have some more widgets (Scaffold, Container, etc) but they are irrelevant.

Comment: If you create a file variable in `build` method, it recreates at next state rebuild. Try to place a file variable to class scope.

Comment: @fartem But I'm trying to do the opposite, I want it to get updated after a change in the file system

Comment: When you loading image with this approach, images cached in memory (more [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.file.html)). You need to try clear cache for update an image.

Comment: @fartem But when the file doesn't exist, it will not get to the `Image.file` part, it will return a `SizedBox` instead

Comment: please show us where you put the `setState`

Comment: And show how to file saving on device.